# Why doesn't SQL always accept expressions in place of integers?

Tags: sql

In an imperative programming language you are allowed to place expression everywhere where an integer is expected. Why in SQL this isn't so? Why doesn't SQL accept something like this:

```
  Create Table Entries (Title Varchar((Select Count(ID) From SomeOtherTable)))
```

When, for example, this works:

```
  Select * From Entries Where id = (Select Count(id) From SomeOtherTable)
```

Now, of course, these examples are silly. I don't really care if I can create tables based on a dynamic information. I want to understand why SQL is different in this regard from, say, C or C# or Delphi, etc. In these languages I know what will work based on intuitive rules. When I am writing a query, I am kind of unsure whether some construction will be accepted: sometimes it will be and sometimes it won't (I am still new to SQL, so maybe this is the main reason).

I am using Interbase 7.5 if this has some relevance.

Comment: Nice question :) For example SQLite expects a `signed number`, not an `expression` : http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#type-name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE` is [DDL (Data Definition Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language), that is defining schema structure of the database while `SELECT` is [DML (Data Manipulation Language)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language), that is working with the data stored in the schema.

You can not mix and match DDL and DML in one query.

Comment: The only exception being CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT which somewhat mixes the line between DDL and DML.  The resulting table's columnar data types will be set to the data types that result from the expressions, unless you specifically override them, as one example.  Not all databases support such mixing (DB2 and MySQL do at least) but it is out there.